# a method for solving a problem in probability

Tags: probability

If the probability that the man aged $60$ will live to be $70$ is $0.65$, what is the probability that out of $10$ men, now $60$, at least $7$ will go up to $70$?

Comment: check the actuarial tables.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_i$ be a 0-1 random variable. $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th man lives to be 70, and $X_i=0$ otherwise.

Assuming that the survival of each person is independent of survivals of others, $X_i$ are independent identically distributed [Bernoulli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) random variables with $\Pr(X_i=1) = p = 0.65$.

The total number of survivors equals $N = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{10}$. Random variable $N$ follows [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) $\operatorname{Bin}\left(10,p\right)$. The probability that at least 7 survive to be 70 years old equals
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \Pr(N \geqslant 7) &=& \Pr(N=7) + \Pr(N=8) + \Pr(N=9) + \Pr(N=10) \\
  &=& \binom{10}{7} p^7 (1-p)^{3}  + \binom{10}{8} p^8 (1-p)^{2} + \binom{10}{9} p^9 (1-p) + \binom{10}{10} p^{10} \\ 
  &\approx & 0.513827{\color\gray{016356}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$